# invalid_client when requesting Amazon Cognito token with code from java spring back end

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I get `{"error":"invalid_client"}` error when I'm running this:

```java
    public static HttpResponse<String> getAuthToken(@NonNull final String redirectUri, @NonNull final String code) {
        return Unirest.post("https://<myUrl>/oauth2/token")
                .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .body("grant_type=authorization_code" +
                        "&client_id=" + CognitoConstants.COGNIITO_CLIENT_ID +
                        "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri +
                        "&code=" + code)
                .asString();
    }
```

the code seems to be correct, so as Client id.

Please, if you know a better way to Get a proper token from Cognito - tell me. Their documentation doesn't exactly explain anything for a noob in Oauth2

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, needed to have another header with encoded in 64bit client:secret

Comment: Could you post your result here?

Comment: It should be possible without client_secret.